# Exact procedure to update access token life time

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have created access token using **AcquireToken** method (with default 1 hour expiration) and tried to login using below command

```
Add-AzureRmAccount -AccessToken "string" -AccountId "string"
```

It produces subscription details as expected by successful login.
After this i tried to update policy as below:

```
Set-AzureADPolicy -ObjectId <ObjectID FROM GET COMMAND> -DisplayName TenantDefaultPolicyUpdatedScenario -Definition @("{`"TokenLifetimePolicy`":{`"Version`":1,`"MaxAgeSingleFactor`":`"2.00:00:00`"}}")
```

But still token got expired in 1 hour.

Did i missed anything ?
what is the exact procedure and order of updating lifetime of token ?a
after setting policy how to ensure token life time ?

[image]
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please show the output about `Get-AzureADPolicy -ObjectId <your policy object id>`?

Comment: Added screenshot in question section.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes#configurable-policy-property-details), you should set **AccessTokenLifetime** property. Please try to use the following command.

```
Set-AzureADPolicy -Id <ObjectId FROM GET COMMAND> -DisplayName "OrganizationDefaultPolicyUpdatedScenario" -Definition @('{"TokenLifetimePolicy":{"Version":1,"AccessTokenLifetime":"1.00:00:00"}}')
```

The following is the snippet from the document.

> **Access Token Lifetime**
>
> **String**: **AccessTokenLifetime**
>
> **Affects**: Access tokens, ID tokens
>
> **Summary**: This policy controls how long access and ID tokens for this resource are considered valid. Reducing the Access Token Lifetime property mitigates the risk of an access token or ID token being used by a malicious actor for an extended period of time. (These tokens cannot be revoked.) The trade-off is that performance is adversely affected, because the tokens have to be replaced more often.

The **MaxAgeSingleFactor** property affects **Refresh tokens**.

> **Single-Factor Refresh Token Max Age**
>
> **String**: **MaxAgeSingleFactor**
>
> Affects: Refresh tokens
>
> Summary: This policy controls how long a user can use a refresh token to get a new access/refresh token pair after they last authenticated successfully by using only a single factor. After a user authenticates and receives a new refresh token, the user can use the refresh token flow for the specified period of time. (This is true as long as the current refresh token is not revoked, and it is not left unused for longer than the inactive time.) At that point, the user is forced to reauthenticate to receive a new refresh token.
>
> Reducing the max age forces users to authenticate more often. Because single-factor authentication is considered less secure than multi-factor authentication, we recommend that you set this property to a value that is equal to or lesser than the Multi-Factor Refresh Token Max Age property.

Comment: AccessTokenLifetime has expiration life time to max of 1 day. But the token should not expire in any case. thats my requirement.

Comment: As you said, the maximum of AccessTokenLifetime is 1 day, AccessToken without any expiry is not allowed.

Comment: I couldn't get you clearly. in that mentioned link i can able to find below code. `@('{
    "TokenLifetimePolicy":
    {
        "Version":1,
        "MaxAgeSingleFactor":"until-revoked"
    }
}')
` what this means ? can't we set like this?

Comment: As you said i have updated policy with max of 1 day. But still access token expired in 1 hour. Generated access token. Updated policy after login with related Azure Ad credentials. Did i miss anything ?

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** Access token without any expiry is a major security risk and it is not allowed in the Azure.

Default expiration of access token is **1 hour**, **minimum is 10 minutes**, and the **maximum is 1 day**.

For more details, refer “[Configurable token lifetimes in Azure Active Directory (Public Preview)”.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes)

Comment: In that article also there is a section to set policy to extend token life time is not to expire. my basic requirement is to set token life time as until revoked

Comment: You can't make access tokens last until revoked. Refresh tokens can last a longer time, but access tokens are max. 1 day. If you manage refresh tokens well, you can always get new tokens before the previous one expires.

Comment: okay how to ensure the token life time after updating access token with max of 2 hours or 1 day.

Comment: You may refer : https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/blog/2017/08/31/changes-to-the-token-lifetime-defaults-in-azure-ad/